# curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection at first request

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl

im trying to authenticate user via xbox live Oauth2.0, but im experiencing this error which appears only at first request (after that it working for few minutes). Im already tried with --sslv*, --tlsv1, --ciphers, nothing helped.

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ curl -v https://xsts.auth.xboxlive.com/xsts/authorize
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 134.170.178.199...
* Connected to xsts.auth.xboxlive.com (134.170.178.199) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to xsts.auth.xboxlive.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to xsts.auth.xboxlive.com:443

root@admin:~# curl -v https://xsts.auth.xboxlive.com/xsts/authorize
*   Trying 134.170.179.106...
* Connected to xsts.auth.xboxlive.com (134.170.179.106) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 696 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the pull function.
```

**CURL and OpenSSL versions on local machine and production**

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ curl --version
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP

root@admin:~# curl --version
curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: i bet its an OpenSSL bug. and your vagrant compiled version of OpenSSL is about 3 years old. try updating to a newer version of OpenSSL and re-compile curl and try again?

Comment: I recompile curl with newest version of OpenSSL
`vagrant@vagrant:~$ curl --version
curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.1.0c
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy`

But still got same error

Comment: this just got interesting. ps, i'm getting the same error on my box: `root@newratma1:~# curl -v https://xsts.auth.xboxlive.com/xsts/authorize
*   Trying 134.170.179.199...
* Connected to xsts.auth.xboxlive.com (134.170.179.199) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 692 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Error in the push function.`

maybe Microsoft is to blame?

Comment: `root@newratma1:~# curl --version
curl 7.50.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.50.1 GnuTLS/3.5.7 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.33 libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.17.0 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets
` - and wget fails too!

Answer (score 0):

i solve that issue by compile and install the curl by http2 support.

you can use this link for that: https://askubuntu.com/questions/884899/how-do-i-install-curl-with-http2-support

Answer (score 0):

I do not know detail of your setup, but the error

> Unknown SSL protocol error

Can occur on following scenarios,

- The server does not like the SSL protocol used
- The server and client are not able to find an agreement on the cipher ( cipher mismatch between server and client )
- The certificate or key has expired

try **openssl s_client** in debug mode for more information